# The font-size shown in browser is different from the set in css

Tags: css, html, viewport

I want to use the meta tag and set the css, the font-size is 30px, but when I typing more code in tag p, the font-size became 38.317px in Chrome browser; please tell me why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            p{
                word-break: break-all;
                font-size: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>ssssssss</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Could not replicate your issue, its `30px` for me.

Comment: Could you press the button behind font-size to check where this value is coming from and screenshot it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and both Chrome and Firefox don't change the font-size.